# Oracle Sql Loader is only inserting 2096 record out of 10000

Tags: oracle

My Control File is given below

```
 OPTIONS(direct=true, rows=50000)
  LOAD DATA
  INFILE GetRLChannelTypeTmItems_636447339624554792.csv
  BADFILE GetRLChannelTypeTmItems_636447339624554792.csv.bad
  APPEND INTO TABLE LX_NHL.TB_RL_CHANNEL_TM_ITEM
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#@$,' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '"'   TRAILING NULLCOLS 
  (ID_CHANNEL_TM_ITEM,ID_CHANNEL_TM,ID_CHANNEL_ITEM,ID_PARENT,NAME 
  CHAR(4000),KEY_LICENSEE,KEY_LICENSOR,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) 
  "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF",CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) "YYYY-MM-DD 
  HH24:MI:SSxFF",RECORD_STATUS)
```

I am using above setting and importing data from `CSV` file where I have 10000 records but `SQL Loader` is hanging after inserting 2096 records.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening

Comment: It may be because of `direct=true`

Comment: I have also tried direct=false but same hanging problem

Comment: When you say hanging, are there any other symptoms? Is a .bad file created? Does a large index exist on the table in question, or are there any taxing constraints? 

10000 is a relatively small number of records - have you tried doing a conventional load rather than direct path?

Comment: when it hangs, do

select * from v$session_wait where sid = [your session id]

to deduce *why* it is hanging.  Then you can look at further diagnosis